# Pandas how to filter date time for different categories?

Tags: pandas, datetime, filter, categories

Here is my original Table

```
col-1   col-2
A       Day-1
A       Day-2
A       Day-4
A       Day-5
B       Day-1
B       Day-2
B       Day-3
B       Day-6
B       Day-7
```

I would like to get rid of all dates after a specific date for each categories, by another pd.series.

For example, if the series is

```
A      Day-1
B      Day-6
```

The original Table would become

```
col-1   col-2
A       Day-1
B       Day-1
B       Day-2
B       Day-3
B       Day-6
```

Is that possible to do this? Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `s` Series, swap order or rows with [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) for select rows before matched values in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['col-1'].map(s).eq(df['col-2']).iloc[::-1].groupby(df['col-1']).cummax().iloc[::-1]
df = df[m]

print (df)
  col-1  col-2
0     A  Day-1
4     B  Day-1
5     B  Day-2
6     B  Day-3
7     B  Day-6
```